# Is this use of Optional bad practice here?

Tags: java, oop, java-8, null, option-type

I wanted to check if my use of Optional here is against the good practices.

```
public Move getChoice() {

    Optional<Move> move = Optional.empty();
    while (!move.isPresent()) {
        System.out.println("Enter move code : R => Rock, P => Paper, S => Scissors");
        move = Move.fromMnemonic(consoleReader.readPlayerInput());
    }
    return move.get();
}




public enum Move 
{
    ROCK('R'), PAPER('P'), SCISSORS('S');

    private final char mnemonic;
    public static Move[] values = values();

    Move(char mnemonic) {
        this.mnemonic = mnemonic;
    }

    public static Optional<Move> fromMnemonic(char playerInput) {
      return Arrays.stream(values).filter(v -> v.mnemonic == playerInput).findFirst();
    }
}
```

My goal was to avoid creating another Enum 'UNKOWN' instance.
I read that using **Optional.isPresent** and **Optional.get** is bad practice. But I can't find any way around using other functions like Optional.ifPresent or Optinal.map as I have to loop while if result isn't valid yet.

Thank you.

Comment: _"I read that using Optional.isPresent and Optional.get is bad practice"_  got a reference for that?

Comment: IMHO that’s to rigid. `isPresent()` and `get()` are low-level and very often better replaced by other methods; not always.

Comment: @OleV.V.you mean that in this situation, those low level methods are acceptable?

Comment: I am still trying to make up my mind. :-) Meaning that you can and it’s not obvious that a better solution exists, depending on taste.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your version of `fromMnemonic` for each invocation you iterate over the all enum values and check for a matching constant. Conversely, you can declare a static `Map<Character, Move>` from mnemonic to enum constant in your enum type and initialize it eagerly at class initialization. Then you can use it inside the `fromMnemonic` method like this.

```
private static final Map<Character, Move> mnemonicToMoveMap = Arrays.stream(values)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m.mnemonic, m -> m));

public static Move fromMnemonic(char playerInput) {
    return mnemonicToMoveMap.get(playerInput);
}
```

And here's how your client looks.

```
public Move getChoice() {
    Move move = null;
    while (move == null) {
        System.out.println("Enter move code : R => Rock, P => Paper, S => Scissors");
        move = Move.fromMnemonic(consoleReader.readPlayerInput());
    }
    return move;
}
```

If you really need to use `Optional<Move>` as the return type of your `fromMnemonic` method, then the body of the method should be like this.

```
public static Optional<Move> fromMnemonic(char playerInput) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(mnemonicToMoveMap.get(playerInput));
}
```

And this leaves your client intact.

Comment: well we can with adding a method to check if map contains character without doing the == null, but I will see if i get suggestions to do it in a more stylish way using Optionals..

Comment: Discussing time complexity is not worthwhile when the number of elements is known to be fixed to three.

Comment: @Holger Makes sense, I have updated the answer accordingly. Thanks.